# Exception 'Fingerprints didn't match.' when starting Android Xamarin.UITest

Tags: android, xamarin, keystore, xamarin.uitest

After updating my dev environment by installing some new android-sdk's and changing java versions, my xamarin.uitest project started failing to install the apk for testing.

The exception I am getting is "Fingerprints didn't match.", which based on the stack trace is being thrown by the method at

```
Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.AndroidTestServerFactory.BuildTestServer(ApkFile appApkFile, KeyStore keyStore, ArtifactFolder artifactFolder, Assembly sharedAssembly)
```

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is regarding the dev keystore, which the uitest framework is using to sign the apk.

While I do not know the details, the solution I found was to remove the keystores from the uitest temp folder. For me, the location of this is temp directory was at C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest.

In the 'uitest' directory, there are multiple directories as shown:

[image]

What I did was removed the directories that started with 'a-', and after which was able to run the test successfully. This I assume created a new keystore.

Comment: Worked in my case. Thank you.